# WooCommerce product-short-description getting renderred TWICE if any class specified

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

This is an odd one, and I'm REALLY hoping someone else has seen this before.

We want a **list** in our product short descriptions.
As long as we don't add any class names to the description, everything is fine.

But, as soon as I try to give any part of it a class name, the whole thing starts breaking.
Specifically, it renders a broken second copy of the short-desc ***directly*** following the opening BODY tag for the page/document.
In that broken instance,  it truncates the short-desc before the first CLASS declaration and guts the closing UL tag.

It does also still display where/how it's supposed to ...in the product summary.

See an example here: < link removed >

BTW, I'm currently on the Avada theme, but I tested with the Twenty-Seventeen theme as well and the problem persisted.
Also, I tested with paragraph and span tags as well and that yielded the same broken results.

Has anyone seen anything like this before?
Any suggestions/ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

I went through all the plugins, and turns out there is one responsible:
**TG Facebook Meta Tags**

All plugins other than that one have now been reactivated, and the problem is resolved.